# How to extract the "href" attribute value from within the closest list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, href

My site has a column of checkboxes with IDs in sequential order like "keepbox1", "keepbox2", etc. Each checkbox resides within a list item, along with a `href` attribute like this:

```
<li>
   <a href="http://iNeedThisUrl.com" class="describer">Title</a>
   <br>
   <input id="keepbox1" type="checkbox" class="kboxes" name="keepbox1"  />
   <label for="keepbox1">Keep</label>
   <div class="tinybox" alt="tinypic1" id="tinypic1" style="display:none;">  
      Content Here
   </div>
   </a>     
</li>
```

There is also an element on the page that I use as button

```
<a><label class="getFiles" for="lightbox-two">Submit</label></a>
```

When a user clicks this button, I have a script that loops through each variation of `keepbox` to see if a user checked it. If a particular keepbox *is* checked, I'd like to extract the href attribute's value in that particular `li`.

So if a user had checked `keepbox1` from the demo code above, I'd like it to alert back "http://iNeedThisUrl.com".

I'm using the following script which successfully identifies a checked keepbox, but it's returning "undefined" in the alert box. I'm guessing I'm not grabbing the attribute properly. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.getFiles').click(function() {
                for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 
                  {
                    if ($("#keepbox" + i).prop('checked')) 
                     {
               var addressValue = $("#tinypic" + i).closest("li").attr("href");
               alert(addressValue);
                     }
                   }
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

1) you have closing anchor tag `</a>` without opening anchor tag as next sibling of div in li. you need to remove it.

2) div elements `#tinypic`+n are siblings of anchor element. You need to use:

```
$("#tinypic" + i).siblings("a").attr("href");
```

or

```
$("#tinypic" + i).prevAll("a").attr("href");
```

or

```
$("#tinypic" + i).closest("li").find("a").attr("href");
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason your first 2 solutions didn't work, but the third one did.

Comment: Is the third solution inferior to the other two in any way? In terms of cross-browser and cross-platform compatibility? If not, I'll just stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".kboxes").each(function(){
 if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
  var addressValue = $(this).closest("a").attr("href");
  alert(addressValue);
  return false;
 }
});
```